# Best practice to Serialize java.time.LocalDateTime (java 8) to js Date using GSON

Tags: java, javascript, serialization, gson

In our recent project we use java 8. I need to serialize java.time.LocalDateTime to java script Date format.

Currently what I did was define a custom serializer to convert LocalDateTime to timestamp.

```
public class LocalDateTimeSerializer implements JsonSerializer<LocalDateTime> {
    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(LocalDateTime localDateTime, Type type, JsonSerializationContext jsonSerializationContext) {
        Instant instant = localDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant();
        Date date = Date.from(instant);
        return new JsonPrimitive(date.getTime());
    }
}
```

then create Gson object using GsonBuilder with my custom LocalDateTimeSerializer

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(LocalDateTime.class, new LocalDateTimeSerializer());

Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
```

Then in Java Script I create a Date object using this time stamp. It's working fine.

I need to know, is this way ok or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

YES, that's the best way.

It's highly recommended to convert a `Time` object into it's `long` type representation when you're going to transfer it from one system to another. This can avoid many problems, such as data formatting and time local in different systems.

And what's more, `long` representation takes only 8 bytes, while string representation takes a little more. Which means `long` representation is more efficient to transfer and parse.

Comment: It is worth noting that a LocalDateTime in java 8 is represented by two longs, one for the date and one for the time, which is in nanosecond precision. By converting to a long by this method, or any other, you're potentially losing precision.  On some systems today, you may get back the same datetime as the original (some still seem restricted to ms precision, with the nano-bits all zeroed out), but on others you will not.

Comment: This is straight up wrong. The _whole_ _point_ of *Local*DateTime is that it represents _clock_ time in the local timezone, as opposed to a Date which is actually a point on the universal timeline. Same goes for LocalDate - its a box on the calendar. Converting to universal time you end up with a value that is only correct in one timezone. Use ISO8601 - it is designed for unambiguous representation of chrono values across platforms.

Answer (score 13):

Java 8 solution from LocalDateTime to Epoch Milliseconds or Seconds:

```java
// to Epoch Seconds
long sec = localDateTime.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).getEpochSecond();

// to Epoch Milliseconds
long msec = localDateTime.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).toEpochMilli();
```

In your case however I see a bug which uses Local Timezone instead of UTC. My recommended solution would be:

```java
@Override
public JsonElement serialize(LocalDateTime localDateTime, Type type, JsonSerializationContext jsonSerializationContext) {
    long sec = localDateTime.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).getEpochSecond();
    return new JsonPrimitive(sec);
}
```

Comment: For local ZoneOffset... `localDateTime.toInstant(ZonedDateTime.now().getOffset()).toEpochMilli()`

Comment: I created a test class in kotlin which shows some stuff was discussed here:
[ZonedDateTimeWithEpochTest.kt]https://gist.github.com/RichardSilveira/a76a4666ec853f9476a7a913d52e7a3c